# Regex for allowing multiple, single words

Tags: php, regex

I have a working regex for when a user can enter only 1 word into a text box.
However, how can I adjust it, to allow 2,3,4,5 single words? At times, I may need to alter the code to only allow 3 words, for example that is.

Here is my regex `^([a-zA-Z_\-\.]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching 2,3,4,5 single words

```
^(\b[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\b\s*){2,5}$
```

For matching 2 or 4 single words

```
^(\b[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\b\s*){2}$|^(\b[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\b\s*){4}$
or
^((\b[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\b\s*){2}|(\b[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\b\s*){4})$
```

But it fails under tests `abc.def` and `abc_def` =( It founds two words. `\b` is the wrong idea with your vocabulary `[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+`...

---

Okay, that's it.

For 2,3,4,5 words

```
^([a-zA-Z_\-\.]+[^a-zA-Z_\-\.]+){1,4}[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+$
```

Notice that now non-alphabet symbols in the end are disallowed.

Comment: It is actually weird but it fails also if you set exact number of words. eg. only 3 words (or 5) - it match 1,2 and 3. [Gskinner/RegExr](http://regexr.com?31s66). Can you explain it?

Comment: regexr.com is broken at my work, i could provide such tests: [one](http://goo.gl/cu5V0) [two](http://goo.gl/qd0Hw) [three](http://goo.gl/NfPj1) [four](http://goo.gl/fTrsS0)